# How to convert "\u002f" to "/" (in c++)?

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding

I have to following string which i get from share point : 
\u002fsites\u002fblabla\u002fShared Documents\u002fkittens.xml

and i'm trying to convert it to : 
/sites/blabla/Shared Documents/kittens.xml

I googled it and found that it is Unicode encoded, but i couldn't find anything that converts it, technically i can write a small function that converts all the "\u002f" to "/" but i don't think it is the right thing to do.

If any one can shed some light on this matter it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: That \u002f is a utf16 encoding for '/'  - you might convert your string to utf8.

Comment: @DieterLücking: I presume he literally gets \ u 0 0 2 f (6 characters). Converting to UTF8 does not change the character count, you'd just end up with \ u 0 0 2 f in UTF-8 (ASCII even, in this case)

Comment: There are a number of different string literal formats that use `\u` escapes. You need to find out which one you've got and use the appropriate decoder because they are not all the same. For example if the above is part of a JSON string literal then use a JSON decoder, but this could produce incorrect output for (say) a C# string literal.

Comment: @bobince As far as I know, the universal character name format is always the same: `\uxxxx` or '\Uxxxxxxxx`, where the x's are hex digits.  (The first format is used for code points in the basic plane; the second for others.)  Different languages may specific different sets of escape sequences, but I would expect any which support universal character names to use the same rules for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a library that solved my problem, and i want to share the solution in case someone else will stumble upon this question.

The library called ICU

And the use is very simple :

```
icu::UnicodeString converter = icu::UnicodeString(in.c_str(),in.length());
icu::UnicodeString newUstring = converter.unescape();
newUstring.toUTF8String(out);
```

when `in` and `out` are `string`.

Comment: You started with a specific problem, and found a general solution. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether there's a ready function in C++ to do that or not , but you can do that by this algorithm :

1-find "\" character in your first string using find function in string class,change it to "/"
2- omit from this point to 4 nexts(incluse u002) and  so on...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string process(string str){
    string result="";
    for (int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
        if(str[i]=='\\' ) {
            result.push_back('//');
            i+=5;
        }
        else
            result.push_back(str[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    string path;
    getline(cin,path);
    cout<<process(path)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Which of course breaks horribly as as soon as ANY other character is sent as a Unicode escape char. BTW, you'd need to remove 5 chars (u002f).

Comment: @MSalters It breaks horribly in any number of cases.  Before writing the first line of code, you have to think about what you should do in all of the possible error cases.  I thought I had some code to do this in my toolkit, but I couldn't find it; I know that I did do it once (handling all of the usual escape sequences, not just `\u`), and it took quite a few lines of code, more than half of which was to handle the special cases which shouldn't occur (but inevitably do).

Answer (score 0):

*If* the string is a string literal, the compiler should take
care of this translation; a sequence `\uxxxx`
is a "universal character name".  If it's data you're reading
from an outside source, I'm not aware of any standard function
which would convert it; you'll have to write your own.  (And
getting it right isn't that trivial, once you add all of the
necessary error checking.)

Comment: I'm reading it from an outside source, where can i find more information about how this type of function should work ?

Comment: @OopsUser The C/C++ standards define all of the legal escape sequences.  Depending on context, you might be happy with just recognizing universal character names (which are also described in several language standards, including C and C++), or you might want to generically handle all escape sequences.  (A universal character name is either `\uxxxx` or `\Uxxxxxxxx`, where the `x` are hexadecimal digits.  You convert the x's to a numeric value, which is the Unicode code point.)