# How to transform unicode to readable string?

Tags: python

I have a list of urls:

```
['https:\\u002F\\u002Furl.net\\u002F800x600\\u002Ff031d92dc2ea2f928e475f27ff84fad2db99b01982ff846e50028f6edc71c140\\u002Fimage.jpg',
'https:\\u002F\\u002Furl.net\\u002F800x600\\u002Ff82ff846e501d92dc2ea2928e475f27ff84fad2db99b019028f6edc71c140\\u002Fimage.jpg']
```

How do I transform them to normal urls I can paste into a browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert "\u002f" to "/" (in c++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237685/how-to-convert-u002f-to-in-c)

Comment: What is the source of this list?

Comment: Oops, the above question is for C++. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527763/python-3-6-cant-convert-unicode-in-a-string

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unicode-escape` codec can transform embedded Unicode escapes.  The string needs to be a byte string, however, hence the `.encode()` first:

```
>>> s = ['https:\\u002F\\u002Furl.net\\u002F800x600\\u002Ff031d92dc2ea2f928e475f27ff84fad2db99b01982ff846e50028f6edc71c140\\u002Fimage.jpg',
... 'https:\\u002F\\u002Furl.net\\u002F800x600\\u002Ff82ff846e501d92dc2ea2928e475f27ff84fad2db99b019028f6edc71c140\\u002Fimage.jpg']
>>> [e.encode().decode('unicode-escape') for e in s]
['https://url.net/800x600/f031d92dc2ea2f928e475f27ff84fad2db99b01982ff846e50028f6edc71c140/image.jpg', 'https://url.net/800x600/f82ff846e501d92dc2ea2928e475f27ff84fad2db99b019028f6edc71c140/image.jpg']
```